# Finding and copying files in subfolders to a unique folder giving them their path names

Tags: bash, loops, rename, copying

I need to do a bash script in order to copy all files which are in various subfolders and sub-subfolders of a main directory to a unique another folder while giving them a new name indicating their source.

Source paths and files are like:

```
MainDir/SubFolderX/SubSubFolderXY/fileZ.dat
MainDir/UnknowName../AnotherUnknowName../AnyFile.anyExtension
```

... Etc

Destination folder with renamed files would be:

```
NewDir/SubFolderX_SubSubFolderXY_fileZ.dat
NewDir/UnknowName.._AnotherUnknowName.._AnyFile.anyExtension
```

Etc

What I know is that there is only 2 levels but the names of the subfolders, the subsubfolders, the files, and their extensions could be anything.